"Pilot duty" rating vs "max switched current" rating of relays
Looking for guidance on when I should be considering the "pilot duty" rating when choosing a relay.
For example, consider the ALDP105W. It has a max switching current of 5A (AC). It also has a C300 pilot duty rating. This means that at 120VAC, it has a "make" rating of 15A and a "break" rating of 1.5A.
Now lets say I want to use a relay to switch 120VAC power to a water pump (or some other relatively inductive load) that is rated for 1.5A.
On one hand, I would say the ALDP105W is a suitable choice because the 1.5A rating on the water pump is well below the 5A max AC switching current of the relay. On the other hand, this might be a poor choice because the water pump is a somewhat inductive load, meaning that the pilot duty rating (may or may not) apply. With a 1.5A rating on the pump and a 1.5A "break" rating on the relay's pilot duty, there is no margin at all.
Which rating - pilot duty or AC max switching current- should I be considering?
